# simultaneous input to 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I intend to create a worksheet in excel with two cells as inputs.
For Ex. A2 is one; and C2 is five
Relationship between A2:C2 = 1:5
Relationship between C2:A2 = 1:1/5
Is there a way to write a script to get this cyclic relationship.
Next time I type 2 in (A2) I see that cell (C2) is 10 
Also if I type 40 in (C2) I see 8 in (A2)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this isn't a place where we will write scripts for you. If you post your code, we can help identify problems. It sounds like you just want to divide two cells. If that's the case, this can be done in excel using formulas, and you probably don't need VBA.

Answer (score 4):

Use a Worksheet_Change in the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab, View Code).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'only A2 and C2
    'If Not Intersect(Range("A2, C2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    'all of columns A and C
    If Not Intersect(Range("A:A, C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Range("A:A, C:C"), Target)
            select case t.column
                case 1
                    t.offset(0, 2) = 5 * t.value
                case 3
                    t.offset(0, -2) = t.value / 5
            end select
        Next t
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = true

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use both `Worksheet_Change()` (to react to specific cell value change) and `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` (to catch ratio before any of the specific cells value change happens) event handlers.

Thus place the following in the wanted sheet code pane:

```
Dim ratio As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    On Error GoTo exitSub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$2"
            Range("C2").Value = ratio * Target.Value2
        Case "$C$2"
            Range("A2").Value = ratio * Target.Value2
    End Select

exitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$2"
            ratio = Range("C2") / Target.Value2
        Case "$C$2"
            ratio = Range("A2") / Target.Value2
    End Select    
End Sub
```